# How do we estimate binomial confidence intervals when there are zero successes or failures?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Imagine I'm performing an experiment where I treat cells with some compound looking for toxicity.  I test $N$ identical cells with the compound and all cells die immediately.  As a function of $N$, how certain can I be that the next sampled cell will die when treated with the compound?

Comment: The classical will the sun rise tomorrow problem! Lots of literature, little consensus.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Lol, yes, I've been having trouble finding an accepted way to proceed.  I suppose I'd like to be as conservative as possible...

Comment: As is well known, Laplace computed this to be $(N+1)/(N+2)$ (I think). As is less well remembered, he also warned that to be confident in this result was, to be brief, nonsense.

Comment: @Did If you were to review some manuscript for publication - where someone is trying to claim a success rate (there isn't one, this is hypothetical) - what would you find reasonable?

Comment: @user71678 I would find my responsibility as a mathematician to thrash savagely this insanity. The misapplications of statistics in the life sciences are one of the great disgraces of the time (as thoroughly and regularly denounced by some practitioners themselves, but to no avail). If all the N cells die, just say that all died, instead of attributing a *probability* to the fact that cell N+1 also dies.

Comment: @Did, it's one thing to not make ridiculous claims using mathematical-sounding language, and another to pretend that all N dying has no probability implications.  If the situation is close to i.i.d., which is a nontrivial statement about the experimental conditions, then just saying the cells die is overly conservative, and starts to become a different kind of ridiculous when N is large.

Comment: @zyx: It was not claimed that all cells die, only that all cells **died**.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I don't understand the correction.  To follow the recommendation and say "all N cells died" might be enough for some purposes, but if probabilities really are important for a problem (imagine pills and humans instead of cells, and we need to know when to stop a medical trial) then it is problematic to state only the raw experimental result and not make some probability calculations.

Comment: I agree there is a quandary. However, to make a probability calculation, we need some sort of model. The model and the reality will never be the same, and one can get valuable information even from an obviously flawed model. However, when no semi-plausible model of any kind presents itself, one cannot make a calculation, one can only have rules of an arbitrary character. Many years ago, through circumstances too complicated to explain, I did some statistical consulting (unpaid) for the med school. It provided enough anecdotes for many a lecture.

Comment: The model is that the trials are close to being independent identically distributed.  If that is not the case, for example, the cells differ in size or other characteristics, then one can ask the same question for other models (if discrete).  There are quite a few things one has to rule out before i.i.d is a reasonable model, but if one can do that, or if one is willing to write the conclusion in conditional form ("the cells died, and if the trials were approximately IID, then ... "), then it is not possible to escape the issue. Re: the edit -- indeed the situation in practice is absurd.

Comment: @AndréNicolas ... sorry, forgot the @ notice.

Answer (score 0):

If what you’re looking for is the standard binomial confidence interval, then answer is P≥alpha^(1/N).  (If the cells are i.i.d. with P the probability that a cell will die, then the probability that N out of N died is Pr[X=N]=P^N.  A confidence interval is a list of all parameter values supported by the data.  If we decide support is that the chance of observing what we did has to alpha or higher, then the lower confidence limit is all P such that P^N≥alpha, which can be rewritten P≥alpha^(1/N).  For example, if N=50, then the lower confidence limit is P≥0.94.)